# Plotly-Dash: How to design the layout using dash bootstrap components?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I'm very new to Dash Plotly and I'm trying to figure out how can I design a layout like this.

[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WesWm.png):

[image]

As I understood, this can be done more easy using dash bootstrap components.
https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai
As a first step I should reproduce the layout (grey tiles) and as a second step, I should add some text and some graphs. Just basic.

Thank you.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You should check out this [link](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/) to learn more about Dash Bootstrap Components, and how to structure your layout.

I have made an example using `JupyterDash` that matches your desired layout.

[image]

```py
from dash import Dash, dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.express as px

# Iris bar figure
def drawFigure():
    return  html.Div([
        dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody([
                dcc.Graph(
                    figure=px.bar(
                        df, x="sepal_width", y="sepal_length", color="species"
                    ).update_layout(
                        template='plotly_dark',
                        plot_bgcolor= 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                        paper_bgcolor= 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                    ),
                    config={
                        'displayModeBar': False
                    }
                ) 
            ])
        ),  
    ])

# Text field
def drawText():
    return html.Div([
        dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody([
                html.Div([
                    html.H2("Text"),
                ], style={'textAlign': 'center'}) 
            ])
        ),
    ])

# Data
df = px.data.iris()

# Build App
app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawText()
                ], width=3),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawText()
                ], width=3),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawText()
                ], width=3),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawText()
                ], width=3),
            ], align='center'), 
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawFigure() 
                ], width=3),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawFigure()
                ], width=3),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawFigure() 
                ], width=6),
            ], align='center'), 
            html.Br(),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawFigure()
                ], width=9),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawFigure()
                ], width=3),
            ], align='center'),      
        ]), color = 'dark'
    )
])

# Run app and display result inline in the notebook
app.run_server()
```

Comment: thanks for the clue and the code. from your code, I see that the maximum width for one full page wide is 12.  how about the height, how much maximum height for all graph just for one fullpage, that's means not need to scroll down to see it?

Comment: @Kristian Haga, why are you using `dbc.Card` as a container for all the other elements (rows, cards)?

Comment: @AndreiKrivoshei I can't remember exactly, I think it was just an easy way to get different background colors by specifying color='dark' on the outer Card.  You can probably just replace the outer Card with a basic Div or some other container.

Comment: This is a beautiful and very simple to forward example. Thank you for that.

Comment: @KristianHaga, this example is great! I would also ask the same question as Wahyu Bram, how to set the height of a graph? for example if I want to divide one row in 2 graphs, but having one graph over 2 rows, and the other one in only 1 row

Comment: how do you make the horizontal width span the complete the width of the window?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - this can be done with dash-bootstrap. Since the screen layout is divided into 12 columns - you'll have to set the width by the number of columns you would like each section to take. So if for example, you need 4 columns, each should be width a width=3.

Your layout would look something like this - 3 rows, the first with 4 columns, the second with 3 columns, the third with 2 columns. After building the layout - you can play with the width of the columns in each row - so it would fit the layout you need

```
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])]),
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])]),
dbc.Row([dbc.Col([content]),dbc.Col([content])])
```

You can see a detailed explanation [here](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/)

Here is a working dash example:

```html
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table_experiments as dt
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])

app.layout = \
dbc.Container\
([
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 1 col 1",style={"width":"100%"})],width=3),
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 1 col 2", style={"width": "100%"})],width=3),
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 1 col 3",style={"width":"100%"})],width=3),
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 1 col 4",style={"width":"100%"})],width=3),
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 2 col 1",style={"width":"100%"})],width=3),
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 2 col 2", style={"width": "100%"})],width=3),
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 2 col 3",style={"width":"100%"})],width=6),
    ]),
    html.Br(),
    dbc.Row([
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 3 col 1",style={"width":"100%"})],width=9),
    dbc.Col([dbc.Button("row 3 col 2", style={"width": "100%"})],width=3),
    ])
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False, port=8050, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Comment: @Napier - if you ask the same question, you'll get the same answer