# How do I get my columns to align side by side in Plotly dash and DBC?

Tags: python, bootstrap-4, plotly, plotly-dash

Trying to get these graphs side by side but for some reason they keep showing up on top of each other. I even tried to adjust the width and now its just two stubby graphs stacked and still not side by side.

(See pic attached)

I followed the instructions listed on this stack question:
[Plotly-Dash: How to design the layout using dash bootstrap components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592900/plotly-dash-how-to-design-the-layout-using-dash-bootstrap-components)

But still cant seem to get it to work. It stacks the rows perfectly but not the columns?

```html
a[![enter image description here][1]][1]pp.layout =dbc.Container([
    #FIRST ROW       
    dbc.Row([
        #COLUMN ONE
                dbc.Col([
        html.Label(['Full Chart']),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='my_dropdown',
            options=[
                     {'label': 'Price', 'value': 'Price'},
                     {'label': 'Volume', 'value': 'Volume'},
                     {'label': 'Positive Tweets', 'value': 'Positive Tweets'},
                     {'label': 'Negative Tweets', 'value': 'Negative Tweets'},
                     {'label': 'Neutral Tweets', 'value': 'Neutral Tweets'},
                     {'label': 'Total Number of Tweets', 'value': 'Total Number of Tweets'}
            ],
            value=['Price'],
            multi=True,
            clearable=False,
            style={"width": "50%"}
        ),html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='the_graph',style={'width': '75vh', 'height': '45vh'})
    ])
    ])
        #COLUMN TWO
        ,dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(figure=fig2, style={'width': '75vh', 'height': '45vh'})])]),
    
    html.Br(),
    #SECOND ROW
            dbc.Row([
                #ONLY COLUMN
                dbc.Col([
    html.Div(dcc.Tabs([dcc.Tab(label = "Tab One", children = [dcc.Graph(figure=fig2)]), dcc.Tab(label = "Tab Two", children= [dcc.Graph(figure=fig2)])]))], xxl = True)])])
#---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is that you are combining `Dropdown` and the graphs in one row so I divided `Dropdown` to one `Row` and graphs to one `Row`. Please refer this below code. Hope this help

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])
app.layout =dbc.Container([
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Label(['Full Chart']),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='my_dropdown',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'Price', 'value': 'Price'},
                    {'label': 'Volume', 'value': 'Volume'},
                    {'label': 'Positive Tweets', 'value': 'Positive Tweets'},
                    {'label': 'Negative Tweets', 'value': 'Negative Tweets'},
                    {'label': 'Neutral Tweets', 'value': 'Neutral Tweets'},
                    {'label': 'Total Number of Tweets', 'value': 'Total Number of Tweets'}
                ],
                value=['Price'],
                multi=True,
                clearable=False,
                style={"width": "50%"}
            )
        ])
    ]),
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(id='the_graph',style={'width': '75vh', 'height': '45vh'})],width={'size':6}),
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(figure={}, style={'width': '75vh', 'height': '45vh'})],width={'size':6})
    ]),
    
    html.Br(),
    #SECOND ROW
            dbc.Row([
                #ONLY COLUMN
                dbc.Col([
    html.Div(dcc.Tabs([dcc.Tab(label = "Tab One", children = [dcc.Graph(figure={})]), dcc.Tab(label = "Tab Two", children= [dcc.Graph(figure={})])]))], xxl = True)])])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Comment: DO I need to have a stylesheet installed as well to make it work? im guessing maybe thats why its not working since I am using dcc elements without a theme

Comment: So try to add stylesheet as `app = dash.Dash(__name__,external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.LUX])`

Comment: @KennethLott did this solve your problem?