# Dash plotly figures jumping around in predefined grid

Tags: python, layout, plotly-dash

In Dash, the layout of a page can be designed using bootstrap components (see for instance [Plotly-Dash: How to design the layout using dash bootstrap components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63592900/plotly-dash-how-to-design-the-layout-using-dash-bootstrap-components)). We can make a 12x12 grid of squares & in my app I make a raster of 4 plotly plots, let's say p1,p2,p3,p4 in the following way:

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dbc

layout = dbc.Container([
             dbc.Row([
                  dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(p1)], width=6),
                  dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(p2)], width=6),
       ]),
             dbc.Row([
                  dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(p3)], width=6),
                  dbc.Col([dcc.Graph(p4)], width=6)
       ])
])
```

I notice that when I resize my browser slightly, the plots can start jumping around, meaning, the 2x2 grid of plots, becomes sometimes a 4x1 grid. Is there anyway I can prevent Dash from doing that, by just resizing the full grid depending on browser size, instead of altering the grid?

MANY THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `width=6` you should use `xs, sm, md, lg, xl`. So you can setting as `xs=6, sm=6, md=6, lg=6`.

[image]